# Check for Property List

Tags: swift, property-list

I'm currently learning Swift 2 on XCode 7 and trying to figure out how to test if a property list is available to read from.

I have a convenience initializer that works but I want to implement a test to see if the propertyList exists, otherwise just create an empty array.

Here's my code far:

**Property List creation and write**

```
let propertyList: NSArray = photoGrid.photos.map { $0.propertyListRepresentation() }

let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    .DocumentDirectory, 
    .UserDomainMask, 
    true)[0] as NSString

let file = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("data.plist")

propertyList.writeToFile(file, atomically: true)
```

**Convenience Init**

```
convenience init(propertyList: NSArray) {
    self.init()

    // test if property list exists {
    self.photos = propertyList.map { (param: AnyObject) -> Photo in
        let pl = param as! NSDictionary
        let photo = Photo(propertyList: pl)
        return photo!
    }
    // } else {
    //    print("Property List does not exist... Created empty object array)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use the URL related API to get the file URL

```
let documentDirectoryURL = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
let fileURL = documentDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("data.plist")
```

Second of all, there is a class `NSPropertyListSerialization` which is preferable to the implicit property list serialization of `NSArray`.

Third of all, in Swift use native collection types rather than the type-unspecified Foundation classes.

This is an `init` method which creates the file URL, checks file exists and assigns the mapped `Photo` instances or an empty `Photo` array to the instance variable.

```
init() {
  let documentDirectoryURL = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
  let fileURL = documentDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("data.plist")
  if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL:fileURL), propertyList = try! NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(data, options: [], format: nil) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
    self.photos = propertyList.map { Photo(propertyList: $0)! }
  } else {
    self.photos = [Photo]()
  }
}
```

The two `try!` expressions are safe because the document directory exists and the property list file has a predictable format.